# Error TextWatcher() no funciona correctamente

Tags: android

Hola me  ha surgido un problema con la clase TextWatcher,he intentado buscar soluciones respecto al tema en este foro y el inglés pero no he encontrado lo que buscaba, tengo este trozo de código en mi método onCreate():

```
    textoBuscado = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textobuscado);


    textoBuscado.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            buscarCadena(textoBuscado.getText().toString());

        }


    });
```

Mi layout se compone de dos editText: textoBuscado y textoContenido.

El método cadena es un método que ejecuta la siguiente acción:

Si en mi editText 'textoContenido' se encuentra la letra "r" y yo escribo una "r" en mi editText 'textoBuscado' esa "r" del 'textoContenido' se coloreara de azul.

Esto funciona correctamente, el problema es que si yo borro la letra "r" de textoBuscado para escribir otra la aplicación se congela se para y tengo que forzar su cierre.

¿Como puedo solucionar este problema? ¿Qué esta pasando realmente?

**EDIT**

El método funciona correctamente pues el texto es coloreado y si ejecuto el método mediante un botón todo funciona correctamente, el problema es que quiero hacerlo con textWatcher.

El método buscarCadena es el siguiente: textoEditado representa el editText "textoContenido" que mencionaba.

```
public void buscarCadena(String cadena) {

    String miTexto = textoEditado.getText().toString();

    String textoAuxiliar = miTexto;

    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(miTexto);

    int guarda = 0;

    while (textoAuxiliar.contains(cadena)) {

        int index = textoAuxiliar.indexOf(cadena);
        int longitud = cadena.length();

        if (guarda == 0) guarda = index;

        ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), index, index + longitud, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        textoAuxiliar = textoAuxiliar.replaceFirst(cadena, " ");

    }

    textoEditado.setText(ss);
    textoEditado.setSelection(guarda);



}
```

Comment: Publica el codigo del metodo `buscarCadena` que donde se produce el error para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Prueba encerrando todo el código del método `buscarCadena()` en un if. Si el valor del parámetro que recibe el método no es nulo, ejecutas el código, de lo contrario no. `public void buscarCadena(String cadena) { if (cadena != null) {...}}`

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, Si lo hago aplicando tu solución ocurre exactamente lo mismo, colorea la primera letra pero al momento de borrarla se bloquea la aplicación.

Answer (score 2):

El problema radica que cuando borras la letra, el editText de búsqueda queda vació y posteriormente en alguna parte dentro del codigo buscarCadena eso esta generando un error, los cambios que pueden darte solucion son los siguientes.

1. Cambia dentro del el textWatcher el metodo que envia la cadena, y cambia al elemento que te llega dentro de la interfaz implementada.

   2. Valida la cadena que te llega, si te llega "" //un elemento vacio, no invoques el metodo buscarCadena, solo deberias limpiar la cadena ya que el elemento de busqueda es vacio (dejar la cadena toda en negro)

      ```
                  textoBuscado.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                          if(!s.toString().equals("")){
                          buscarCadena(s.toString());
      }
                          else {
                         //Limpiar la cadena ya que la busqueda de letras es  vacia.
                         }
                  }

                  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                  }
                  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                  }
              });
      ```